# ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext. with spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2-scala2.13

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am provisioning, spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2-scala2.13.

Java 11 and python 3.10 are installed.

But when running spark-shell, I get the error `"ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext"`

It was tested with the versions that are available:

spark-3.0.3-bin-hadoop2.7

spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2

spark-3.1.3-bin-hadoop2.7

spark-3.1.3-bin-hadoop3.2

spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7

The environment variables are already organized:

JAVA_HOME, HADDOP_HOME, SPARK_HOME

Validate a solution that is on stackoverflow in the file `spark-defaults.conf => spark.eventLog.enabled false.`

the same problem continues.

Thanks for any suggestions you can give me.

````
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
22/03/07 14:45:35 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.addReplClassLoaderIfNeeded(Executor.scala:909)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.<init>(Executor.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.<init>(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.start(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:220)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:581)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2690)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:949)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:943)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:114)
        at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:5)
        at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:4)
        at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<synthetic>:6)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print(<synthetic>:5)
        at $line3.$eval.$print(<synthetic>)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:670)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1006)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$doInterpret$1(IMain.scala:506)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:36)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:116)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:43)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:505)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$doInterpret$3(IMain.scala:519)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.doInterpret(IMain.scala:519)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:503)```
````